# How to do a complex gradle composite build project with include, includeBuild, allProjects, and subProjects?

Tags: java, gradle

I want to do the following Gradle folder structure in a project.

```
.
├── project/
│   ├── fruit/
│   │   ├── banana/
│   │   │   └── build.gradle.kts
│   │   ├── apple/
│   │   │   └── build.gradle.kts
│   │   ├── build.gradle.kts
│   │   └── settings.gradle.kts
│   └── shared/
│       ├── common/
│       │   └── build.gradle.kts
│       ├── util/
│       │   └── build.gradle.kts
│       └── build.gradle.kts
├── build.gradle.kts
└── settings.gradle.kts
```

In the outermost `build.gradle` I want to do `allprojects` and `subprojects` to consolidate dependencies. Then, each `build.gradle` will have the dependencies of its folder/subfolder.

This is the outermost `settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = "root"

include("fruit")
include("fruit:apple")
include("fruit:banana")
include("shared")
include("shared:common")
include("shared:util")
```

For `apple` and `banana`, I want to use `includeBuild` in the `fruit/settings.gradle` to include the `shared` modules.

This is the following `build.gradle` for the `fruit` folder (though it cannot be resolved and it doesn't work):

```
dependencies {
  implementation("com.example.shared:common")
  implementation("com.example.shared:util")
}
```

This is the following `settings.gradle.kts` for the `fruit` folder:

```
includeBuild("../shared/common")
includeBuild("../shared/util")
```

The dependencies in my `project/fruit/apple/src/com.example.fruit.apple/Main.java` file still do not get resolved.

Comment: what is `includeBuild` doing here? Can't you just use a project dependency?

Comment: Isn't `settings.gradle` supposed to have `includeBuild` in order to create a composite build? I followed [`this Gradle documentation`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_composite_builds_basics.html).

Comment: Sure, but from what you've described, I don't see a *need* for composite builds.